# Producing single-line comments with HAML?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I'm trying to generate a comment on a single line at the end of an HTML file:

```
<!-- generated by SERVER1 -->
```

---

I have tried

```
/
  generated by #{@server_name}
```

But this outputs it over 3 lines -

```
<!-- 
    generated by SERVER1 
-->
```

I've tried

```
/ generated by #{@server_name}
```

But that doesn't evaluate the `@server_name` var -

```
<!-- generated by #{@server_name} -->
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It's still an open issue: https://github.com/nex3/haml/issues/313. I think you're stuck with the multiline comment for now, even though nex3 says single line interpolation should work.

Comment: ahh lameo. If you would like to add your comment as an answer I'll give you a tick. Cheers

Comment: This is now fixed in Haml master, https://github.com/haml/haml/commit/dd530babee5b894f5433db59d2e7517b3d9a9c50 It should be in Haml 4.1 (or 5 – https://github.com/haml/haml/issues/761).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Just as you can drop back to raw HTML output when you want, so you can drop in raw HTML comments, even with interpolation.

This template:

```
- @foo = 42
#test1
  /
    Hello #{@foo}
#test2
  <!-- Hello #{@foo} -->
```

Produces this output:

```html
<div id='test1'>
  <!--
    Hello 42
  -->
</div>
<div id='test2'>
  <!-- Hello 42 -->
</div>
```

*Tested with Haml v3.1.4 (Separated Sally)*

Answer (score 3):

It's still an open issue: [github.com/haml/haml/issues/313](https://github.com/haml/haml/issues/313). I think you're stuck with the multiline comment for now, even though nex3 says single line interpolation should work.